# Restrict DBSet to a subset of entities

Tags: entity-framework

I am building a multi-tenant application using EF 4, I have a shared database an many entities have a CustomerID field. I was wondering if there was a way I could enforce a CustomerID query at my DBSet level from my DBContext.

I was hoping I could specify a CustomerID when I create my DB context, and wrap the DBSets to always include a (x => x.CustomerID == custID) so I don't need to worry about adding this logic all over my application, but I haven't been able to find anything that suggests its possible

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **strongly recommend** doing this in a *separate* service layer on top of your DbContext since it will be much easier to enforce at that level.

If you insist on doing it at the DbContext level, here is a sample that does what you want.

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly int _customerId;

    public MyContext(int customerId)
    {
        _customerId = customerId;
    }

    public DbQuery<MyEntity> MyEntities
    {
        get
        {
            return (DbQuery)Set<MyEntity>().Where(e => e.CustomerId == _customerId);
        }
    }

    protected override OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>();
    }
}
```

The big problem with this is that you cannot ensure that the query returned from MyEntities won't be further modified to include entities for other customers.

Comment: Thanks Brice, I will probably look at implementing this logic in a service layer as per your recommendation.