# Can you use Lambda expressions against ObjectSets in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5

I am using EF5, although I am sure it is a more general EF Question.

I cannot get the following to work. I keep getting casting error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[StdOrgUser]' to type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet`1[StdOrgUser]'.
```

For the code:

```
    public ObjectSet<StdOrgUser> StdOrgUser
    {
        get
        {
            if ((_StdOrgUser == null))
            {
                _StdOrgUser = base.CreateObjectSet<StdOrgUser>("StdOrgUser");
                _StdOrgUser = (ObjectSet<StdOrgUser>) _StdOrgUser.Where(r => r.IsActive == false);
            }
            return _StdOrgUser;
        }
    }
```

It compiles fine. Intellisense enables me to choose LINQ operators etc. It is when I run it, that I get the above runtime error.

Where am I going wrong?

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ObjectSet` class implements (amongst other things) `IQueryable` and `IEnumerable`, both of these interfaces have an extension method `Where`, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535040.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx). Neither `IQueryable` nor `IEnumerable` (which are the respective return types of the extension methods) can be cast back to `ObjectSet`.

The following line of code cannot be evaluated until run time:

```
_StdOrgUser = (ObjectSet<StdOrgUser>) _StdOrgUser.Where(r => r.IsActive == false);
```

but if you remove the cast the code will not compile:

```
_StdOrgUser = _StdOrgUser.Where(r => r.IsActive == false);
```

---

UPDATE

For querying you could change the return type of `StdOrgUsers` from `ObjectSet` to `IQueryable` but you lose all the other methods such as `Add`, `Attach` etc. You can't apply a standard filter using this technique. You could have an extension method called `ActiveUsers()`

```
public static IQueryable<StdOrgUser> ActiveUsers(this ObjectSet<StdOrgUser> users)
{
    return users.Where(r => r.IsActive == false);
}
```

what you need to do is remember to use it in each query (not very pretty but it does clearly show intent)

```
var results = myContext
    .StdOrgUser
    .ActiveUsers()
    .Where(//some filter);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So what is your suggestion for altering the code so that it will work?

Comment: Thanks for this. I am a little confused as to whether I could use this approach in my EF context file which is where the above code is taken from. I do want to alter an application code. I just want to current LINQ calls to StdOrgUser, for example, to now retrieve only non archived records in the StdOrgUser table.

Comment: Which is:     public partial class myEntities : ObjectContext
    { etc.... public ObjectSet<T> T

Comment: @SamJolly I don't think you'll be able to get this working exactly as you'd like ...

Comment: @SamJolly All roads lead to the need to define your own implementation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269433/restrict-dbset-to-a-subset-of-entities